# Razor Login page with sqlite and each user having its own session

Tags: c#, web, razor

I want to create a login script for my razor page.
The Razor project is using SQLite as a database.

I don't know where to store current session users info, to work with it.

Right now I have a OnPost method where I create the CurrentUser object with the parameters from database where UserName matches the HTML form input UserName:

```cs
public void OnPostLogin()
{
    User CurrentUser = new(
       Convert.ToInt32(db.ParametryUzivatele(UserNameLogin).Rows[0]),
        db.ParametryUzivatele(UserNameLogin).Rows[1].ToString(),
        db.ParametryUzivatele(UserNameLogin).Rows[2].ToString(),
        db.ParametryUzivatele(UserNameLogin).Rows[3].ToString(),
        Convert.ToInt32(db.ParametryUzivatele(UserNameLogin).Rows[4]),
        Convert.ToInt32(db.ParametryUzivatele(UserNameLogin).Rows[5])
    );
}
```

I don't know where to store this right now, so the "current user" would be accessible from every other Page and it would be accessing the accurate user for every login session.

The model for USER is looking like this:

```cs
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? UserName { get; set; }
    public string? Password { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public int LevelOfAccess { get; set; }
    public int Verified { get; set; }

    public List<User>? Users { get; set; } = new();

    public User(int IDu, string UserNameu, string Passwordu, string Emailu, int LevelOfAccessu, int Verifiedu)
    {
        Users.Add(new User(ID,UserName,Password,Email,LevelOfAccess,Verified));
        ID = IDu;
        UserName = UserNameu;
        Password = Passwordu;
        Email= Emailu;
        LevelOfAccess = LevelOfAccessu;
        Verified = Verifiedu;
    }
}
```